# how to disable previous months in kendo month picker

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-datepicker

I have a kendo date picker in  which only months are shown.Now i want to disable previous months of current month to disable so user will not be able to enter previous month.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jayesh Goyani</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="date"></div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var myDatePicker = $("#date").kendoDatePicker().data("kendoDatePicker");
            myDatePicker.min(new Date()); //This code line will hide previous date from date picker
        }); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Update 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jayesh Goyani</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .disabledDay {
            display: block;
            overflow: hidden;
            min-height: 22px;
            line-height: 22px;
            padding: 0 .45em 0 .1em;
            cursor: default;
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <input id="datepicker" style="width: 150px;" />

    <script>
        disabledDaysBefore = [
          +new Date("10/20/2015")
        ];

        $(document).ready(function () {


            var p = $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
                value: new Date(),
                dates: disabledDaysBefore,
                change: onChange,
                month: {
                    content: '# if (data.date < data.dates) { #' +
                    '<div class="disabledDay">#= data.value #</div>' +
                    '# } else { #' +
                    '#= data.value #' +
                    '# } #'
                },

                open: function (e) {
                    $(".disabledDay").parent().removeClass("k-link")
                    $(".disabledDay").parent().removeAttr("href")
                },
            }).data("kendoDatePicker");
        });
        function onChange() {
            var tillDate = new Date(disabledDaysBefore[0]);
            var selectedDate = new Date(kendo.toString(this.value(), 'd'));

            if (tillDate > selectedDate) {
                tillDate = tillDate + parseInt(1);
                $("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker").value(tillDate);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: I dont want to hide previous month from calendar.I just want to disable it.

Comment: disabledDay class is not applying..i am still able to select previous month but on selecting no date is showing there.

Comment: Could you please create a new page and test above logic in it? It might be possible some other existing js/css affected the above code.

Comment: I created new page...but still same problem coming.                                         Actually div with class disabledDay is not creating which you created in month in datepicker.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `disableDates` property and specify a function to check the date is before the current date, roughly along these lines:

```
$("#monthpicker").kendoDatePicker({
    start: "year",
    depth: "year",
    format: "MMMM yyyy",

    disableDates: function (date) {
        var currentDate = new Date();
        if (date.getFullYear() <= currentDate.getFullYear() && date.getMonth() < currentDate.getMonth()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thnx...but i dont know the logic for getting previous month.